# Resolving a many to many relationship in an RPG game

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

In an RPG game a character can choose from a list of skills, which in turn are stored in a unique skill list for that character.

The problem being that there is still a many to many relationship between skills and skill list that I would like to resolve.

I've read through the other articles and I am still none the wiser, can anyone shed some light on this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you got so far? you haven't really given us enough of a starter to be able to help you.

Comment: Initially I had a character entity with four skill fields the user could fill from a list with many options. 

However through normalisation it made sense to separate the skills chosen for that character into its own table with a compound primary key consisting of Character_ID and Skill_ID. 

...and its finally clicked, I needed to add an additional Unique field to the table. 

char_skills_id
character_id
skills_id

This means that each record in the char_skills table only links to a single skill, but each skill can appear in many character_skills. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why there would be a many to many relationship between skills and skill list.  That sounds like a many to one relationship.  But if you really mean you are trying to link the `characters` to the `skills` then:

You will need a third table that links the `skills` table to the `characters` table, something like the following:

Table: **characterskills**

```
characterid
skillsid
```

Then using SQL you can retrieve a master list of all characters and all of their skills:

```
SELECT c.charname, s.skillname FROM
characters AS c
INNER JOIN characterskills AS cs ON cs.characterid = c.id
INNER JOIN skills AS s ON cs.skillsid = s.id
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/942643/1/0) demonstrating the above.

Comment: I needed to add one more field but it now works perfectly, thanks!